# Unrecognised selector sent to instance during core data migration

Tags: swift, model, migration, mapping

When updating my app, I need to add a new field to a Core Data entity, populated based on the contents of 2 other fields.

I have the function defined in my Entity Migration Policy as:

`-(NSString *)addParentFaction:(NSString *)name type:(NSString *)type;`

and in my mapping model as:

`FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "addParentFaction::" , $source.factionname, $source.factiontype)`

When I run the code, I get the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CoreDataUpdatesPolicy addParentFaction::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282534280'

If I change the function declaration as follows then it works.

`-(NSString *)addParentFaction:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)type;`

What's the difference please?

Comment: Please consider the tags you're using for your question. Right now you only added some quite generic tags and the [core] tag (*Use this tag to refer to processor cores or questions related to threads and parallel processing.*) is most probably unrelated to your question. Usually, you should at least tag the language and/or used framework to attract the right experts to your question. Most tags have a tag description and usage guidance. Check the used tags for relevance and also check if [core-data] is the right tag.